# Gedit command not working in kali linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, gedit

Why Gedit command not working in kali linux terminal?

I am using **kali** in **VMware** and i am very new at it. Some basic commands are working fine but problem is when i am using **gedit command** to edit text file in gui, **gedit does not work** rather *terminal says - * "**gedit: command not found**" this.. Do i have to do something manually or actually what is the problem..? And i don't find any clear solution in online.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

Although I am not sure, what the actual error here is, but purging the package will help.

You can try this

```
sudo apt-get purge gedit gedit-common
sudo apt-get clean
```

After this try reinstalling with

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Moreover, you should Prefer AskUbuntu and SuperUser for such questions, you can expect a detailed and possibly faster response.